# Accessing the outer alias from the inner query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a query that would search
in the product label and/or in the product attribute values.

In terms of tables, I have:

- product
- product_has_attribute (which binds a product to an attribute_name and an attribute_value)
- attribute_value
- attribute_name (not required for my query)

I'm almost there, I think I should use group_concat,
but I'm stuck with a condition inside a subquery.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
select
    p.id,
    p.label,
    (
        select
        group_concat( distinct label separator ', ')
        from (
            select
                v.label
                from attribute_value v
                inner join product_has_attribute h on h.attribute_value_id=v.id

        ) as ttt
    ) as attr_values

from product p
having
label like :search
or attr_values like :search
```

This is not too bad as it searches in the product labels, but the problem of this query is that it searches
in ALL attribute values, but I want to search only in the attribute values of the current product,
so I tried this:

```
select
p.id,
p.label,
(
    select
    group_concat( distinct label separator ', ')
    from (
        select
        v.label
        from attribute_value v
        inner join product_has_attribute h on h.attribute_value_id=v.id
        where h.product_id=p.id

    ) as ttt
) as attr_values

from product p
having
label like :search
or attr_values like :search
```

But now it says: "Unknown column p.id".

How can I get my query to search in both the product label and the product attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the extra unnecessary level of SELECT. MySQL should allow reference to the outer query from one level in.  Burying it deeper (two or more levels), it can't be referenced.

Make `attr_values` a single correlated subquery... just one `SELECT`.

Something like this:

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.label
     , ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT v.label ORDER BY v.label SEPARATOR ', ')
           FROM attribute_value v
           JOIN product_has_attribute h
             ON h.attribute_value_id = v.id
          WHERE h.product_id = p.id
       ) AS attr_values
  FROM product p
HAVING p.label     LIKE :search
    OR attr_values LIKE :search
```

Comment: you're awesome. Thanks a lot.